# Additional Play config file

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I need to move some properties out of *application.conf* and into another config file, say *secure-application.conf*. Is there any way I can have properties loaded from two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can in Play 1.x! Just add this line to your application.conf

```
@include.override=secure-application.conf
```

Make sure the additional .conf file is also in the /conf folder.

If you are interested, you can check the relevant function in the Play.java file here https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/Play.java#L430

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Play 1.x, as your tags suggest, then the answer is that you cannot as far as I know. The only alternative is to set up the configuration file for several environments as per [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/ids).

If you use Play 2.x then you can, using the `include` keyword to import a conf file into another